# Ruby hyphen separated float numbers regex troubleshooting

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm having an issue I'll try to represent through code.  My regex extracts the two numbers in this string, converts them to doubles, and stores them in an array.  The instance where the regex doesn't work is when there is only a single digit. I've provided sample output of the values stored in the array in the comments in the code.

```
each_row = ["5.8 - 3.0%"] #works
each_row = ["5 - 71%"]    #doesn't work
each_row = ["5.0 - 7%"]   #doesn't work
each_row = ["5.0 - 71%"]  #works

each_row.map do |row|
  value_pair = row.scan(/\d+.?\d+ - \d+\.?\d+/).map do |token|
    token.split(" - ").map(&:to_f)
  end

  puts value_pair[0][0] #5.8
  puts value_pair[0][1] #3.0

end
```

Comment: The class after the dot should be optional too. Now `/\d+.?\d+ - \d+\.?\d`. It should be `/\d+.?\d* - \d+\.?\d*` to make the decimal "optional".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use optional non-capturing groups

```
/\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s+-\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)?/
```

Explanation:

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - a noncapturing optional group (`(?:...)?`) that matches a dot followed with one or more digits
- `\s+` - one or more whitespace symbols

With `scan`, you need a noncapturing group in order not to extract the value captured with this group.

*Some more thoughts*

You have `\d+.?\d+` that matches 1+ digits followed with 1 or 0 dots followed with 1+ digits. The two pluses require 2 digits. What options do you have beside the already suggested one above?

If you allow values like `.05` you can use `\d*\.?\d+` that will match 0+ digits followed with an optional (1or 0) dots followed with 1+ digits. This won't match integer values with a dot at the end (eg. `54.`).

To match floats or integers with  a dot at the end, you can use `\d+\.?\d*`.

By playing around with `+`, `*` quantifiers and with optional groups you can adjust the expression suggested to whatever requirements you might have in future.

Comment: He's not using the match, however it is very likely that scan will indeed return the value matched by the non capturing group, but not as it's own group - just within the overall matched expression.  This regex I think is better than mine, there was no need for the alternation

Comment: The only other use case I can think of would be negative values like `-0.75 - -0.95%` or `-.75 - -.95%`. I'm assuming the alternate regex parts in your answer will work for all scenarios listed in my question as well as the examples I give in this comment?

Comment: I just confirmed your answer doesn't work for `-7 - -6.7%` ugh! regexes are a college course on their own!

Comment: That all was not in your initial requirement: to match one digit values. Adding optional values is not hard if you follow my advice. Here it is, built from the bits in my answer: [`/-?\d*\.?\d+\s+-\s+-?\d*\.?\d+%?/`](https://regex101.com/r/eJ4sJ1/1). One more, universal regex is [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html): `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?`.

Comment: Excuse me, why did you unaccept the answer? Did you check my last comment?

Comment: a short question, is there any difference between `(.*?)` and `(.*)?`?

Comment: @Shafizadeh: It depends on the language and what method it is used in.

Comment: Ah . . . So there is a different, ok well I will figure it out. By the way I have an idea for you . . . As I know about you, you are an expert in RegEx. So you can create a website to gets a few strings *(as input)* and gives a pattern according to those strings *(as output)* ... I'm not sure creating a website like that is possible, but if it is possible then it would be a great website.

Comment: I apologize.  I think I accidentally unclicked it.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is expecting a digit, maybe a period and then one or more digits (so at a minimum two digits).  You could perhaps use non capturing groups like this:

`/\d+(?:\.\d+|\d*) - \d+(?:\.\d+|\d*)/`

I'm not fluent in ruby, so I'm not sure if row.scan will support this usage sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This works

`(?<first>\d+(\.\d+)?)\s*\-\s*(?<second>\d+(\.\d+)?%)`

You can use names groups to access named sub-expression matches

Try rubular.com, online ruby regular expression playground

Answer (score 0):

```
each_row = []
each_row << "5.8 - 3.0%" #works
each_row << "5 - 71%"    #doesn't work
each_row << "5.0 - 7%"   #doesn't work
each_row << "5.0 - 71%"  #works

each_row.map do |row|
  value_pair = row.scan(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/).map(&:to_f)
  puts value_pair.first
  puts value_pair.last
end
```

Answer (score -2):

```
"5.8 - 3.0%".scan(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/) # => ["5.8", "3.0"]
"5 - 71%"   .scan(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/) # => ["5", "71"]
"5.0 - 7%"  .scan(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/) # => ["5.0", "7"]
"5.0 - 71%" .scan(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/) # => ["5.0", "71"]

"5.8 - 3.0%".scan(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/).map(&:to_f) # => [5.8, 3.0]
"5 - 71%"   .scan(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/).map(&:to_f) # => [5.0, 71.0]
"5.0 - 7%"  .scan(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/).map(&:to_f) # => [5.0, 7.0]
"5.0 - 71%" .scan(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/).map(&:to_f) # => [5.0, 71.0]
```